# How to iterate through a arraylist and print the index of the containing word?

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to know how to iterate through a arraylist and print out all the index's containing a number that the user put in the scanner. If the number is not in the scanner then it would print out value is not in the list. I have two classes in my program.

Below is my Entertainment Class:

```
         public class Real_Entertainment 
      {
            String BookName; 
            String Author; 
            double Rating; 
            int Purchases;


public Real_Entertainment(String BookName, String Author, double Rating, int Purchases)
{
    this.BookName = BookName;
    this.Author = Author;
    this.Rating = Rating;
    this.Purchases = Purchases;
}
public void setBookName(String BookName)
{
    this.BookName = BookName;
}
public void setAuthor (String Author )
{
    this.Author = Author;
}
public void setRating (double Rating)
{
    this.Rating = Rating;
}
public void setPurchased (int Purchases)
{
    this.Purchases = Purchases;
}


    }
```

Below is the main class that contains the arraylist:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    public class Real_Main 
    {




        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {


    ArrayList<Real_Entertainment> print = new ArrayList<Real_Entertainment>();
    Real_Entertainment Book1 = new Real_Entertainment("The Nickel Boys ", "Colson Whitehead", 4.3, 500000);
    Real_Entertainment Book2 = new Real_Entertainment("Olive, Again", "Elizabeth Strout", 6, 321000);
    Real_Entertainment Book3 = new Real_Entertainment("Gingerbread", "Helen Oyeyemi", 2, 681000);
    Real_Entertainment Book4 = new Real_Entertainment("On Earth We're Briefly Gorgeous", "Ocean Vuong", 2, 421000);

    print.add(Book1);
    print.add(Book2);
    print.add(Book3);
    print.add(Book4);



 findPrimitiveValue(print);


}

public static void findPrimitiveValue(ArrayList<Real_Entertainment> print)
{
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a Numeric Value:" );
        int input = scanner.nextInt();
        boolean foundInfo = false;
        for(int i = 0; i < print.size(); i++)
        {
            if(print.get(i).() == input || print.get(i).() == input)
            {
                System.out.println("This is the information found: " );
                System.out.println()
            }
        }

}

   }
```

I have tried to set the value of the purchases = to the value that the user inputted I kept getting an error.

Comment: *"I kept getting an error."* - could you include the error?

Comment: Sure, Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 The method getPurchases() is undefined for the type 
        Real_Entertainment
 The method getPurchases() is undefined for the type Real_Entertainment

Comment: Well, that one is pretty self-explanitory. You have no mehtod `getPurchases()`...

Comment: I understand that but what would I use to check to see if it matches, I had a method called getPurchases()

Comment: `if(print.get(i).getPurchases() == input)` Although I must say `print` is a terrible name for a list of objects... consider naming it `realEntertainments`. Use meaningful variable names.

Comment: Thanks, the getPurchases method is wrong is there anyway I can do it without a creation of a method.

Comment: I found about using .contains but I don't know how to get the indexes.

Comment: Hey welcome back again. I didn't point this out yesterday but it's not recommended to start variable names with a capital letter, because that's reserved for class names to keep the code cleaner. That's why Book1 is blue in the print.add(Book1); statement when you post the code on stack overflow, it's labeling it as a class.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you need? Add an example of what a specific input would be and what the program should output so that we understand what you're looking for.

Comment: Sorry, here is the input the user types in a number for example 2 and it should print out the index  EX: On Earth We're Briefly Gorgeous", "Ocean Vuong", 2, 421000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refactored your code for

- class, field and parameter names according to conventions,
- turning your `Book` class into a Java Bean which also has a `toString()` method for easy printing,
- using less cryptic names in general,
- using Java streams for nicer collection handling.

I also added an example of how you can e.g. search for an exact match in number of purchases for a book. I also added an additional book with the same number of purchases so we can see more than one search result.

**Data class:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q60461642;

public class Book {
  private String name;
  private String author;
  private double rating;
  private int purchases;

  public Book(String name, String author, double rating, int purchases) {
    this.name = name;
    this.author = author;
    this.rating = rating;
    this.purchases = purchases;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Book{" +
      "name='" + name + '\'' +
      ", author='" + author + '\'' +
      ", rating=" + rating +
      ", purchases=" + purchases +
      '}';
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
  }

  public void setAuthor(String author) {
    this.author = author;
  }

  public double getRating() {
    return rating;
  }

  public void setRating(double rating) {
    this.rating = rating;
  }

  public int getPurchases() {
    return purchases;
  }

  public void setPurchases(int purchases) {
    this.purchases = purchases;
  }
}
```

**Driver application:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q60461642;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Application {
  private static List<Book> books = Arrays.asList(
    new Book("The Nickel Boys", "Colson Whitehead", 4.3, 500000),
    new Book("Olive, Again", "Elizabeth Strout", 6, 321000),
    new Book("Gingerbread", "Helen Oyeyemi", 2, 681000),
    new Book("On Earth We're Briefly Gorgeous", "Ocean Vuong", 2, 421000),
    new Book("Perfume", "Patrick Süskind", 6, 500000)
  );

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    printBooks();
    findBooksByNumberOfPurchases();
  }

  private static void printBooks() {
    System.out.println("Books list:");
    books.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
    System.out.println("\n");
  }

  private static void findBooksByNumberOfPurchases() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the number of purchases to search for:");
    int input = scanner.nextInt();
    books.stream()
      .filter(book -> book.getPurchases() == input)
      .forEach(System.out::println);
  }
}
```

**Console log:**

```
Books list:
Book{name='The Nickel Boys', author='Colson Whitehead', rating=4.3, purchases=500000}
Book{name='Olive, Again', author='Elizabeth Strout', rating=6.0, purchases=321000}
Book{name='Gingerbread', author='Helen Oyeyemi', rating=2.0, purchases=681000}
Book{name='On Earth We're Briefly Gorgeous', author='Ocean Vuong', rating=2.0, purchases=421000}
Book{name='Perfume', author='Patrick Süskind', rating=6.0, purchases=500000}


Enter the number of purchases to search for:
500000
Book{name='The Nickel Boys', author='Colson Whitehead', rating=4.3, purchases=500000}
Book{name='Perfume', author='Patrick Süskind', rating=6.0, purchases=500000}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: can you explain the use of the package package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q60461642;

Comment: It is just a package name that I chose in my private test project. I usually use my own domain name plus stackoverflow plus question number when adding new sample code, that's all. You can use whatever packages names you like in your own project. I just don't like questions or answers posted with anonymous package name.

Comment: Thank you so much I really appreciate you spending the time to help me. I have marked the question as answered I just had a thought thinking if I can do the same thing but for the author.

Comment: The way to show appreciation for an answer, a question or even a comment is to [upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) it. But for that you need 15 reputation points first. Anyway, thank you. 

Comment: Is there a way to do it for the author too? Should I create a separate question for this?